# I need to know why this app's output is : 1243

Tags: java

```
class A{
    public A(int i) {
        System.out.println(1);
    }
    public A() {
        this(10);
        System.out.println(2);
    }
    void A() {
        A(10);
        System.out.println(3);
    }
    void A(int i) {
        System.out.println(4);
    }
}

public class MainClass{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new A().A();
    }
}
```

I don't understand the output of this code. I am a beginner and I really want to know why is this happening, the execution track or what happens when this code runs?

Comment: In order for us to explain the parts you don't understand, you need to let us know which those are.  When you say "I really want to know why is this happening", which "this" are you referring to?

Comment: Why 4 is printed before 3

Comment: contrcution takes place before method calling - so the base constructor is called which in turn calls the int-constructor - hence 1 before 2. then A() is called which calles the method overload with int first then outputs 3. the int overload prints 4. You could have gotten to that answer using a Debugger and Breakpoints in less time it took me to type this ...

Answer (score 2):

1. You create new instance of A class with empty constructor. `new A()`
2. In empty constructor, first call is the constructor with the value `this(10)`.
3. Int the constructor with int value you display "**1**". `System.out.println(1)`
4. Then it returns back to empty constructor and call "**2**". `System.out.println(2)`
5. Next, you call the method with no parameters in it. `.A()`
6. And it call the the method with parameters. `A(10)`
7. Then it prints "**4**". `System.out.println(4)`
8. Also returns back to previous method and print "**3**" as last operation. `System.out.println(3)`

https://i.imgur.com/i5l8kTA.png

Sorry for my English.